# Which value should I assign my digitalized features?

Tags: qgis, interpolation, digitizing

I have a scanned an old document that contains geochemical interpolated values (no way to work with the digital file). This is the original image:

[image]

And this is the digitalization I made from it:

[image]

Now, given that the original image is an interpolation of geochemical measures taken in field, which values should I give to each features of my polygon?

For example the crescent moon shape in the upper left corner has a maximum value of 100 (in the original file). Is the half of the original value a good idea (so 50 in this case)?

Someone has any suggestion?

I hope I made myself clear.

p.s. software used: QGIS 2.0

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you digitalize the discrete points given in the map? The value beneath the point should be the source for the isolines.

If you prefer the curves, take the lowest value found inside.

Answer (score 3):

The result of the interpolation that you digitized  is represented in classes instead of continuous values. Therefore each color represent a interval of values, something like:

- < 100
- 100 to 250
- 250 to 500
- > 500

(Note that the limits could be inclusive or exclusive)

Now, if you plan to do some algebra analysis with it, classes and categories might not suitable for it, and you might need to reclassify it. You could use the lower or the hightest value in your class, it depends of the results you plan to get. I would use the worst case scenario for the analysis

If I'm correct, you also have points with values between your contour lines, so, you could digitize both contour lines and point, and create a raster surface from it. For that you can use the interpolation plugin (Raster > Interpolation > Interpolation).

Comment: Using the discrete values of each line is a straightforward solution. And easier. Thanks!